# Where is the windows api function InitCommonControlsEx() in MinGW libraries

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mingw

I use MinGW for 32 bit windows. I use the windows common controls, so I must call InitCommonControlsEx() from the windows API. MinGW linker is unable to find this function, even if I explicitly link with the Commctrl.lib (or the minGW .a version libcomctl32.a).

Where can I find the right import library for InitCommonControlsEx() ?

Comment: do you mean linking against Comctl32.lib, rather than commctrl.lib?

Comment: MinGW system has a different naming convention, but I try to find out what the right name is.

Comment: The right name is libcomctl32.a, you can see that if you do an `objdump -t libcomctl32.a`. Are you sure this is a linker error? What version of MinGW do you have? What command line are you using to compile and to link?

Comment: I specified '-Wl-llibcomctl32.a' on g++ command line. If I enter the full path of libcomctl32.a on my machine, it works (e.g. the function symbols from the library are resolved). There is something wrong with the library search algorithm, or I am using the wrong options?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to link libcomctl32.a, then you need to omit 'lib' & '.a' and then convert it to -l

Example:

```
-lcomctl32
```

This only works on gnu gcc and it's derivatives (Cygwin, Mingw, Clang, etc). 
But on MSVC & C-Builder the library names is not converted, so you can pass Comctl32.lib to the linker directly.